# Property set for object not called

Tags: c#, properties, get, set, inotifypropertychanged

Would appreciate some help with what must be a basic language issue but I can't find the answer. This is a windows 8 store app, but could be any C# XAML. I have a clsRecord with two items(below):
My problem is the SET only get's called for Name. It doesn't get called for the object NumQuestions. I partly understand this is because the calling function is getting a reference to the object with GET. What is the correct way to fix this so it also calls the SET? Thanks for any help.

public class UserRecord : INotifyPropertyChanged

```
{
    public UserRecord()
    {
        _NumQuestions = new Collection<int>();
    }
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _Name)
            {
                _Name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
    private Collection<int> _NumQuestions;
    public Collection<int> NumQuestions
    {
        get
        {
            return _NumQuestions;
        }
        set  // this never gets called
        {
            if (value != _NumQuestions)
            {
                _NumQuestions = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("NumQuestions");
            }
        }
    }
   etc with the notify ...
```

Have another class creating a list of the above

```
public class UserRecords : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<UserRecord> List {  get; set; }
    public UserRecords()
    {
        List = new ObservableCollection<UserRecord>();
    }
    public void ClearCurrentUserScore()
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < List[CurrentUserIndex].NumQuestions.Count; i++)
        {
            List[CurrentUserIndex].NumQuestions[i] = i; // only GET is called
            List[CurrentUserIndex].Name = "X";  // SET is called as expected
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first case `List[CurrentUserIndex].NumQuestions` returns an instance of `Collection<int>`.  This means the `[i]` expression binds off of `Collection<int>` not the `UserRecord` type.  Hence the `set` is never called because the set actually occurs in the indexer of `Collection<int>`.

Instead of using `Collection<int>` you should use `ObservableCollection<int>`.  Additionally delete the `set` method and only provide a `get`

```
private ObservableCollection<int> _NumQuestions;
public ObservableCollection<int> NumQuestions
{
    get
    {
        return _NumQuestions;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Well it seems to work by changing to an ObservableCollection and getting rid of the SET. But now I am confused why it works if the NofifyPropertyChanged never gets called. Isn't that what triggers the databinding to update?

Comment: @KenHutchinson the `ObservableCollection` itself is raising the appropriate events for WPF to hook into